# Django - using captcha on third party applications

Tags: django

My Django site is vulnerable to spam, so I would like to include captcha protection.  The problem is that a lot of components are from third party sources, and don't include captcha verification.  While i could modify their views, that would effect the code's portability/upgradability, so I would rather not. I can only modify their templates.

I have solution, but it is a bit messy, and before I start implementing, I want to see if anyone has a better one.

My solution is as follows:

1) Redirect all Post forms on the site to targert a "captcha bounce" app that will programatically reconstruct their post request, check if the captcha is correct, add a verification token to the post, then redirect back to the original post target.

2) Implement a new type of middleware that will check all post requests.  If the post request is not targeting the "captcha bounce" url, the middleware will return an error unless the verification token is present.

As i said before, this seems needlessly messy.  Does anyone have a better idea?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on app message but:

- you can usually wrap their views into your views and add extra processing
- you can extend their forms to add your captcha fields
- you can add template-tag that is extra javascript check and just add it to your templates.

Comment: The second two points are doable, but the first seems impossible.  The only way I can see of wraping their views into mine would be by modifying all the url targets, which would not be trivial.

Comment: Can you give link to one app that you're trying to modify?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  This should be doable just by using middleware.  Just give it a list of views that it should check for captcha correctness. In the case of a wrong response, it cuts the post out of the request and/or activates some sort of error variable.  Much simpler.